# Http.Context in playframework filters

Tags: session, filter, playframework

I use play 2.5.0. I can't get Http.Context.current() in custom filter. As I understand this is because of filters work in new threads. I need Http.Context to check if user is in session before work with his request. EssentialFilter allows us to work with Executor from the user thread. Maybe I can get context from executor? I need Http.Context.current().session(). Or map of all sessions on server. Than I can compare SESSION_KEY with data in map.

```
private final Executor executor;
@Inject
public SessionFilter(Executor executor) {
    super();
    this.executor = executor;
}

@Override
public EssentialAction apply(EssentialAction next) {
    Http.Context ctx = getHttpContext(executor);
    //Need to get ctx from executor
    checkIfUserInSession(ctx);
    return EssentialAction.of(request -> {
        Accumulator<ByteString, Result> accumulator = next.apply(request);
        return accumulator.map(result -> {
            return result;
        }, executor);
    });
}
```

Does somebody have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters are fit to the tasks that need to process every request in every route, like zipping: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters

The task you describe commonly resolving by action compositions (and request handlers)

An example of the solution: [Intercept request and check authorization in playframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841240/intercept-request-and-check-authorization-in-playframework)

**Update**

> Is there some way to use ctx (Http.Context) in filters?

Yes. [Http.Context is building from the request](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play/src/main/java/play/mvc/Http.java).

```
    public Context(Request request) {
        this.request = request;
        this.header = request._underlyingHeader();
        this.id = header.id();
        this.response = new Response();
        this.session = new Session(JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(header.session().data()));
        this.flash = new Flash(JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(header.flash().data()));
        this.args = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        this.args.putAll(JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(header.tags()));
    }
```

In the `Filter` you have access to the `RequestHeader`. `Request` is a subinterface of the `RequestHeader` but `Context` does not use the special methods of the `Request`. So you can build `Context` on your own form the `RequestHeader`

Or better, you just can take information that you need from the `RequestHeader`.

Based on the play source code, you can get the `Http.Session` like this:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions;

... 

Http.Session session = new Http.Session(JavaConversions.mapAsJavaMap(requestHeader._underlyingHeader().session().data()));
```

It's a looks a little bit hacky, but you can use a "documented way" as well:

```
requestHeader.cookies().get("PLAY_SESSION").value()
```

But then you will need to find the way how to parse that cookies, because they looks like `c62d95d166b40c2cfcac88ae72c06e4bef12db5c-param1=111`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right. For this task we can use action compositions. In this case we can get user ctx. It works the same to filter. It gets up before route start. In my task it is completely enough. But what about filters. They give us ability to work with request and response. Is there some way to use ctx (Http.Context) in filters? Thank you.